# Hard disk setup for Ubuntu installation

Tags: 11.10, installation

I have the following hard disk setup:

> 1. C:\ Win 7 OS disk NTFS
> 2. D:\ Recovery Disk NTFS
> 3. F:\ General NTFS
> 4. G:\ General NTFS
> 5. SYSTEM NTFS
> 6. HP_TOOLS NTFS

The HD is 500GB in size and is a dynamic disk with the partitions as mentioned above.

The C:\ drive is the Windows 7 OS disk. It has a lot of space. Should I shrink it and create a new partition out of it and install ubuntu (dual boot) there or shrink a partition other than the OS partition. Note that the disk is a dynamic disk and has 6 partitions (thanks to HP). I imagine it is better to install a different OS( and bootloader) in the partitions at the 'edges' like C:\ or G:\ . Also, which file system is it better to install ubuntu in? ext4 or ntfs? If I uninstall ubuntu in the future, can I reclaim an ext4 partition using windows?

EDIT:  Oh rats. The disk is a dynamic disk! I [read](https://superuser.com/questions/89304/ubuntu-9-10windows-7-dual-boot-dynamic-disks) that dual boot cannot be done on a dynamic disk - it only permits one OS to be installed. Any methods to convert dynamic disk to basic disk needs deleting the dynamic disk. However I saw some [tools](http://partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html)  which claimed they will magically convert dynamic to basic without data loss.

Answer (score 0):

For your configuration I think a Wubi install would be the best.

- Pros: you don't need any partition making, you don't need any resize, you can safely remove from windows
- Cons: 2-3% slower than bare metal install (you would not notice)

If you are on windows, and insert a live cd/usb it will autorun, and give you the option to install ubuntu inside windows.

Comment: I have a Ubuntu 11.10 i386 live CD. My system is a 64-bit Win 7 system. The option to 'Install Ubuntu inside Windows' doesn't show up - both while booting with live CD and while installing through windows. Any idea why?

Comment: Download directly wubi (it will download the working iso file for your system) http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer